# Authenticator GetUI draws behind status bar

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-statusbar

I made an app in xamarin.android which makes user log in to google using xamarin.auth and OAuth2. The problem is, when i start the activity for login UI, the webview shows behind the status bar. I have a navigationdrawer in my project, but it has the fitsSystemWindows set to true. I have tried moving the fitssystemwindows around, changing it etc., but nothing really worked.

Thanks in advance :)

**-EDIT-**

Here is a screenshot: [GetUIBehindStatusBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uurvX.png). My layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawerheader"
        app:menu="@menu/leftdrawermenu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I use this command to display the UI:

```
StartActivity(authenticator.GetUI(this));
```

Comment: any screen shot and code description?

Comment: Added a screenshot and my layout, any more things needed?

Comment: Where is the webview container of your screen shot? And in the NavigationView should set `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: I do not have a container - the StartActivity(authenticator.GetUI(this)); is from an OAuth2Authenticator class instance

Comment: I have test the google oauth2 but i have a title bar on the screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDQ1p.png). How did you get the UI without title?

Comment: It may be coming from my style:
    '<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>'

Comment: And also the parent of the style is AppCompat.Theme.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `<name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` will not only set the status bar be translucent but also put the view shows behind the status bar.

I suggest you remove the `android:windowTranslucentStatus` or set the value is false and remove the `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</it‌​em>` because it will set the status bar transparent.

And the customer style code should be like as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

If you want to use  `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</it‌​em>` please use the minimun sdk 21. This feature is added in android API 21 above.

The screen shows as below:

[image]

Comment: I do need the 'windowTranslucentStatus="true"', because i have a navigationDrawer which is supposed to draw behind the statusbar - if i get rid of it the statusbar goes black and drawer is no longer displaying below it

Comment: @Tored As a workaround, when you click a logon OAuth button or something else, you can open an activity with another theme without  `'windowTranslucentStatus="true"`. And in the `OnCreate` function run the google OAuth code.